# Typescript "Cannot find name 'firebase'" Firebase reserverd URLs

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am using Firebase reserved URLs as per:

```html
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.6/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/7.14.6/firebase-storage.js"></script>
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
```

However, in my apps entrypoint `index.ts` file (which is transpiled to `index.js` `<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>`),

```js
const storage = firebase.storage();
```

creates the typescript error `Cannot find name 'firebase'.`, which makes sense since `firebase` is a global object and not defined in `index.js`. How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will actually work fine. But the TypeScript compiler complains that it can't find the global `firebase` object, which is correct.

When using Firebase with a build system like yours, you'll typically want to use the npm version of the Firebase SDKs. This is covered in the Firebase documentation under [setting up the SDKs using a module bundler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#using-module-bundlers).

Alternatively you can stick to your current global imports, but then use the trick that David East describes in [TypeScript's new import() types feature explained](https://davidea.st/articles/typescript-2-9-import-types):

> ```
> declare var firebase: import('firebase');
> const app = firebase.initializeApp({ /* config */ });
> ```